# What tools are available on Windows to simulate/emulate network issues?

Tags: windows, networking, http, reverse-proxy

I am looking for tools for Windows that can act as a reverse-proxy in front of a server to introduce various networking issues like jitter, delays, or packet loss.

My preference is a software solution that will work on Windows.  Httpd mod_proxy doesn't appear to support such a configuration, and googling for a tool in this category is proving fruitless.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I find clumsy wonderful :

http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html

> clumsy makes your network condition on Windows significantly worse,
>   but in a managed and interactive manner.

[image]

Comment: This this is awesome, no install or drivers. Many other solutions either didn't work and required installing network drivers.

Comment: Clumsy is great, but it only lets you put a max lag time of 3000ms which isn't great. I need a tool that can let me simulate terrible Internet connectivity.

Comment: @MrPablo Just build it yourself then... See https://github.com/jagt/clumsy/blob/master/src/lag.c

Comment: I'm sure there are uses for this tool, but in my case of trying to test a WebSocket based application, it simply did not work. Still looking for a good tool to help with that specific use case.

Comment: for whatever reason the lag specified does not reflect the actual lag that gets up to 20-30, no matter if I put 3000 in the lag field. It still gets worse though but not as much as I want

Comment: So this tool can delay, drop, rearrange, and even _tamper_ with all network packets without even requiring an install or proxy setup?  Is that... alarming to anyone else?

Comment: It does still rely on a kernel driver. The program uses WinDivert, and per [WinDivert's docs](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#installing) "[t]he WinDivert driver is automatically (and silently) installed on demand whenever your application calls WinDivertOpen(). The calling application must have Administrator privileges."

Answer (score 2):

If you're just testing how your app will repsond to ill-behaved networks, you could do worse that fire up a linux box in front of it with [Wansim](http://code.google.com/p/wansim/) - I know, you wanted something ON the windows box... but probably doing the delayage there is an unfair test, as you've already bypassed a  bunch of the stuff that is under test (eg how the OS & hardware handles packet loss).

I think you're not going to find web proxies to induce this sort of nastiness - far too high level.

Apologies if "testing your app's resilience" is not what you are after... thought i'd make an assumption rather than ask and forget to reply ;)

Comment: My actually goal is to test a client's reaction, and verify some changes I am planning to make will improve the situation.

Answer (score 1):

http://4sysops.com/archives/free-tmnetsim-network-simulator-simulate-network-latency-and-packet-loss/ ?

Also, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117754/can-you-recommend-a-windows-based-network-emulator

http://www.akmalabs.com/downloads_flowmatrix.php - site tweaks my "be wary" sense a bit, but the software looks interesting.